# How to rotate several vertices to a single direction?

Tags: particles, vertex-groups

This is the upper point of view of the low poly environment I'm doing; the vertices selected are not pointing to the direction the viewport is looking from:

[image: My map]

and I know that because when I scatter the trees using these vertices to map the trees with a particle system, the tip of the trees are pointing to many directions but most of them to the upper side of the map, you can notice in the left side of the screenshot the pine is pointing somewhere near my POV:

[image]

**How do I make the pines point to a specific direction? Should I start by making the vertices point to the direction I want or the pines made by the particle system can be rotated all to a common direction?**

Comment: First debugs I almost always do is check for duplicate vertices (select all > M > by distance), and recalculate normals (select all > mesh > normals > recalculate outside). If that doesn't work, you could select the vertices then `Mesh > normals > point to target` (then pick a target - options are listed at top after performing operation - select it, check target options, then Ctrl+Z if you have to). If none of that works, perhaps consider Geometry Nodes (Like particles but _way_ better)

Comment: do you want all to point towards the same point or do you want all to be oriented the same way? For the latter, if your trees are hair, enable Advanced option in the Hair panel, enable Rotation option, and choose the right Orientation axis?

Comment: Ahhh my God, @moonboots, that worked, thanks! But I want to test Christopher answer too so I can mark them as correct answers